# Mvc route classic asp pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic, routes

I am converting an asp classic (.asp) to mvc4. The site is fine, but when I try to map the legacy pages to the new routes it fails big time.

I just want to : default.asp to / or pageA.asp to /NewPageA

When I try to map the old pages , looks like the asp classic handler intercepts first the request and try to find the page .asp, but as doesn't exist, it throws 404 error.

I am mapping wrong ? my mapping is like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("DefaultOld", "default.asp", new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexOld" });
routes.MapRoute("MenuOld", "menu.htm", new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexOld" });
routes.MapRoute("RecepcaoOld", "recepcao.htm", new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexOld" });
routes.MapRoute("EntradaPorOld", "entrada_por.htm", new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexOld" });
```

Is possible to tell the server to ignore the classic pages and let the mvc route to intercepts the request and act as it should ?

I am using IIS 7.

I tried this solution here (http://blog.abodit.com/2010/04/a-simple-redirect-route-handler-for-asp-net-3-5-routing/), works fine to map tp aspx pages, but when I try to use with asp or htm, it doesn't work at all. So I think I need t disable the handler od classic asp, is that correct ? but in the htm side, the StaticHandler if I disable it, the images and all static resources would not work well, correct ?
cheers

Comment: Why not `MapPageRoute`?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?